# Show multiple images Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagettftext

I want to create multiple images using `imagettftext` and show it in the view file.
I have used this code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php.

When i place the above mentioned code in my controller it works perfectly, but want to know how can i render multiple images in the view file  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better to use ci Image manipulation library rather than using core php functions for image manipulation. Here the doc http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: Store the images name in the db and fetch their name from db whenever you want to use them in view.

Comment: According to me you should create a separate table in the db that will store all images related to the user.and when displaying images in the view you can easily fetch the images from that table as per user_id...This is the standard way to do this...

Comment: Do you suggest any other way as i will be creating hundreds of images in runtime and saving it than i will be showing it, it may consume a lot time ...